# Android Cocos2dX JNI Bridge

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

I am new to using Cocos2d-X and am just experimenting using JNI in my application. So here is my java code

```
public class JNITest {
    public static native void printSomething();

    public static void printSomethingFromJava(){    
        printSomething();
    }

}
```

I use javah to generate a header file, and implement a C function in my MyScene.cpp file

```
void notify(){
     CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->postNotification("hello",NULL);
}

extern "C" {
    void Java_com_nbs_test_JNITest_printSomething(JNIEnv *, jclass){
        CCLog("THE jni call is successfull");
        notify();
    }
}
```

The CCLog message is printed, so my android -> c++ bridge is working. In the constructor of 
MyScene.cpp i set up a Listener

```
MyScene::MyScene() {

    if (!CCLayer::init()) {
        return;
    }
     CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->addObserver(
                      this,
                      callfuncO_selector( MyScene::printSomethingInCpp),
                      "hello",
                      NULL);
```

and in the  MyScene::printSomethingInCpp i just print this

```
void MyScene::printSomethingInCpp(){
    CCLog("Its goton hererew---------------------------->");
}
```

The log message in PingoScreen::printSomethingInCpp is never printed. I dont know if the problem is with my JNI call or with the Observer pattern ?

## comeplete code

```
#ifndef PINGOSCREEN_H_
#define PINGOSCREEN_H_
#include "RequestHandler.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "cocos-ext.h"
#include "box2d.h"
#include "json.h"
#include "GLES-Render.h"

#define MY_SCREEN_RES "hello"
class PingoScreen: public cocos2d::CCLayer{
public:
    bool init();
        PingoScreen();
        ~PingoScreen();
        static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();
        CREATE_FUNC(PingoScreen);
        void printSomethingInCpp(CCObject *pObject);
        static void notify();
        static PingoScreen* getInstance();

        void setListener();
private:
        cocos2d::CCSprite *ball;
        RequestHandler* r;

};
```

AND

```
#include "PingoScreen.h"
#include "SampleRequest.h"
#include "platform/android/jni/JniHelper.h"


#define PTM_RATIO 32;
using namespace cocos2d;
static PingoScreen* _mInstance = NULL;

CCScene* PingoScreen::scene() {
    CCScene* pScene = CCScene::create();
    PingoScreen* pingoScreen =PingoScreen::create();
    pScene->addChild(pingoScreen);
    return pScene;
}



PingoScreen* PingoScreen::getInstance(){
    if(!_mInstance){
        _mInstance=PingoScreen::create();
    }
    return _mInstance;
}




void PingoScreen::setListener(){
}


bool PingoScreen::init(){
    if (!CCLayer::init()) {
            return false;
    }

        // CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->postNotification("hello",NULL);
     CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->addObserver(
                 this,
                 callfuncO_selector(PingoScreen::printSomethingInCpp),
                 "hello",
                 NULL);

        CCSize pSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
        CCSprite* backgroundSprite = CCSprite::create("room5.png");
        backgroundSprite->setAnchorPoint(CCPointZero);
        this->addChild(backgroundSprite, -1);
        return true;
}
PingoScreen::PingoScreen() {


}

PingoScreen::~PingoScreen() {

}


void PingoScreen::printSomethingInCpp(CCObject *pObject){
    CCLog("Its goton hererew 1212112----------@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@212121212@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@------------------>");
}

void PingoScreen::notify(){
    CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->postNotification("hello",NULL);
}

extern "C" {
    void Java_com_nbs_test_JNITest_printSomething(JNIEnv *, jclass){
        PingoScreen::notify();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`callfuncO_selector` takes function pointer of method which accept `CCObject*` as argument.

Your method `MyScene::printSomethingInCpp()` should be like this:

```
MyScene::printSomethingInCpp(CCObject* pSender)
{
   // your code
}
```

Comment: If i move the post notification call to anywhere in the Cocos2d-X code it works fine. The notification been generated from the C code does not find any observers ?

Comment: Where did you called `printSomethingFromJava()` method?

Comment: I havent called that. My activity onStart method calls the JNI method.