# Cocos2dx: push notification when app is clossing

Tags: android, ios, cocos2d-x

Can we implement like the title i told in cocos2dx.
I mean, when use not open app for 7 days(example).
We will push a notification, can we implement it by Cocos to cross platform?
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be cross-platform. Because cocos2d-x doesn't handle that but no one is stopping you to implement it for different OS's on your own,

you can use macro definition CC_PLATFORM_TARGET to write target code.

Implement iOS like
[how to create local notifications in iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047117/how-to-create-local-notifications-in-iphone-app)

Implement Android like
[Local Notifications in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076165/local-notifications-in-android?rq=1)

If you need help in writing obj-c/c++ hybrid code, 
[How can I use C++ with Objective-C in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683101/how-can-i-use-c-with-objective-c-in-xcode)

Or JNI bridge
[Android Cocos2dX JNI Bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487144/android-cocos2dx-jni-bridge)

Comment: Cool, if it helps, share the love

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what exactly you want, but I think for doing this you can use an AlarmManager like this :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, heure);   //choose here for a week
        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

and user a BroadcastReceiver for the notification like this :

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context,
            YourActivity.class);   //to open when click the notification

    resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    // Because clicking the notification opens a new ("special") activity,
    // there's no need to create an artificial back stack.
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.courier_blanc)
    .setContentTitle("Title")
    .setContentText("Message");

    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);   //TODO enlever pour le mettre avec l'intent
    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    // Sets an ID for the notification
    int mNotificationId = 001;
    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Application.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

} }
```

Comment: Thank odiiil, This is only for android, i'm using cocos2dx to develop a mini game, so i want to implement by C++

Comment: yes I think so. Maybe you can find similar code for C++